# Why do PCB traces go back and forth?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Why do traces on PCB's go back and forth? My first thought was it acts as a delay however the length of it should make the delay unnoticeable, if nearly non-existent. Image of example:

[image]

Comment: Not '[cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable)'. PCB tracks or traces. (I understand that English might not be your first language.)

Comment: They're used on high-speed boards where trace length can significantly affect the signal timing. Some of the traces wiggle to match their lengths to the other traces (which are originally a little bit longer) to ensure the signals reach the receivers at the same time.